# Adding a char after a certain value and condition of string Java

Tags: java, string

I have this pattern of date: 2000-03-05 represented by YYYY-MM-dd

The problem is, the date value can be empty, so I would get "2000-03-".

I was trying to override this behavior by using replace all, to replace the null value, but as I get the value in String, there is no null or empty value.

```
String.join("-", date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay()).replaceAll(" ", "c")
```

How should this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: `String.join("-", date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay().length() > 0 ? date.getDay() : "c")`?

Comment: `the date value can be empty, so I would get "2000-03-"` - What do you mean by saying *"date value can be empty"*? What is the type of `date`?

Comment: Date is a Object with three String - Year, Month and Date. On all of this three values, the user can pass them as null or empty. So in this case, I would like to replace them if a a specific char.

Comment: @iRaven Why do you need to reinvent the wheel? You can use classes from the `java.time` package, like [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use a [Conditional Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1.4) aka, the `ternary (?:) operator` where `(a ? b : c)` says *`if a is true, evaluate b, else evaluate c`*. and do it like this.

```
String.join("-", date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 
     date.getDay().isEmpty() ? "c" : date.getDay());
```

Here's an example using a `record` as a simple Date class.

```
record Date(String getYear, String getMonth, String getDay) {

Date date1 = new Date("2002", "10", "30");
Date date2 = new Date("2002", "10", "");

System.out.println(String.join("-", date1.getYear(),
        date1.getMonth(),
        date1.getDay().isEmpty() ? "c" : date1.getDay()));

System.out.println(String.join("-", date2.getYear(),
        date2.getMonth(),
        date2.getDay().isEmpty() ? "c" : date2.getDay()));
```

prints

```
2002-10-30
2002-10-c
```

But you may want to provide more information including your use case as more constructive help could result.  And make certain you aren't using the old `Date` class but those classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WJS comment,
I would have put everything in a String.format in order to make things clearer and more readable.

```
String.format("%s-%s-%s", date1.getYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDay().isEmpty() ? "c" : date1.getDay());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat as below:

```
String sDate ="2020-08-";  
Date date = null;
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    sDate = sDate + "c";
}  
System.out.println("sDate= " +"\t"+ sDate);
```

Output: sDate=  2020-08-c

Comment: Don't be recommending `SimpleDateFormat`.  It is outdated and flawed.  All Date formatting and manipulation should be done using classes from the java.time package.  And what happens if the user gets an unrelated parse exception?